# Problem in installing internet explorer 8

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, ie

I am installing internet explorer 8 using playonlinux. However after downloading and extracting all the files a pop up arises saying:

```
The installation does not support your operating system's current service pack version
```

Please someone help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Question is why you want IE8?  It would be a security nightmare now.  Don't think even windows will allow install.  If you really need it, try to install windows in a VM.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use playonlinux use wine and the latest winetricks. I have managed a successful installation of ie8 on Bionic Beaver using the following 3 steps:

**1. Install Wine and Winetricks**

Install the repository Wine but a more 'cutting edge' version of winetricks:

```
sudo apt-get install wine cabextract
sudo apt-get remove winetricks
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
sudo mv -v winetricks /usr/local/bin
```

**2. Set a 32bit prefix and install ie8**

You will need a small amount of command line athleticism to create the 32bit prefix required by ie8's installation:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_32 winecfg
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_32 winetricks ie8
```

**3. Run this aged browser**

To get it all running from the command line run the following:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_32 wine 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore'
```

And there you will see this ancient, Windows browser in all of its glory! Obligatory screenshot here of the successful installation on my own system:

[image]