# Internet Explorer 8 on Wine Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wine, winetricks, javascript

I recently installed IE8 on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop using Wine and Winetricks. The installation has completed successfully but the .exe file located in /home/woop/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe won't run. It just doesn't start whatever I do.

I need to open it because I am trying to play a game on Byond and that requires IE8 and some Javascript plugin (?) that is used for some things in the game. So I would like to open IE8 in order to install Java on it or something.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Would be safer for your Ubuntu if you could use a VM.  IE8 with wine will cause security holes.  Use a VM with Windows, so if something happens, just delete.

Comment: I'm not going to use IE8 as my browser, just need to open it in order to install Java or something.

Comment: Found this answer, but still be very careful with which sites you open in IE8 to install stuff.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194126/problem-in-installing-internet-explorer-8

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I've done and it wont open.